# I am getting an error saying 'The trial period for this product has expired.' on my SharePoint Foundation 2010 server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed a server few months back. We were using it for quite some months and it was behaving nicely. But, one fine day when one user tried to access a site on this server, which he was referencing daily, he got an error saying 'The trial period for this product has expired.'.
Being an administrator user I am still able to log in to Central administration. But, none of the sites in site collection are accessible.

I was under impression that SharePoint Foundation 2010 is a free product.

Can anybody help me in this regard ?

Comment: Were you using any of the Standard or Enterprise features?  Also, are you certain that you installed just Foundation and not the trial version of Standard/Enterprise?

Comment: No we are not using any Standard or Enterprise features. Actually i am not sure because i didn't installed it myself but our system team informed me that it is Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 4):

It is a bug with the health analyzer.  See http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/644ab342-4eaa-468c-95c1-f345a4f65f26 for a quick solution on how to disable that health analyzer rule and thus fix your issue.

Comment: That didn't worked for me at least. Finally i took the backup and restored it on a fresh installation.

Comment: you said you took the back up and reinstalled it. What all backup you took? was it the entire site collection backup or only the Content DB backup alone?

Answer (score 0):

My ShaerePoint 2010 list would generate "The trial period for this product has expired" each time I tried to edit a particular item.  List Ribbon / List Settings / Form Settings will give a choice of SharePoint Form or InfoPath.  Found InfoPath set (must not be installed correctly); switched to SharePoint Standard.  Upon refresh I see a single radio button with a caption to the right "Customize the current form using Microsoft InfoPath"  Since then I have been able to edit the list item; no more "expired" message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
1.  Open IIS Management Console 
2.  Go to the Application Pool Page 
3.  look which users has been used for SharePoint 
4.  add this users to the local administration group 
5.  iisreset
```